# A script that only opens 1 division at a time on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

A html/css/js script that only opens 1 division at a time

This script works perfectly! I put it together after spending days looking for more professional code - it doesn't need any resource files its simple - but its ugly code. How can I shorten it with a single function without having to add jsQuery. Close all div and just identify the one clicked to open it. Surely it can be done with a single function.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>  div { width:100%; height:100px; text-align: center; display: none; }  </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <center>
            <nobr>
              <button onclick="hs1()"> Content div1 
              </button> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <button onclick="hs2()"> Content div2 
              </button> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <button onclick="hs3()"> Content div3 
              </button> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <button onclick="hs4()"> Content div4 
              </button> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <button onclick="hs5()"> Content div5 
              </button>
            </nobr>
          </center>
          <hr>
          <center>
            <nobr>
              <a href="#!" id="" onclick="return hs1()"> Content div1 </a> | 
              <a href="#!" id="" onclick="return hs2()"> Content div2 </a> | 
              <a href="#!" id="" onclick="return hs3()"> Content div3 </a> | 
              <a href="#!" id="" onclick="return hs4()"> Content div4 </a> | 
              <a href="#!" id="" onclick="return hs5()"> Content div5 </a>
            </nobr>
          </center>
          <hr>
          <div id="div1" style="background-color:#ff00ff; display:block;">DIV element 1.  
          </div>
          <div id="div2" style="background-color:#ff0000;">DIV element 2. 
          </div>
          <div id="div3" style="background-color:#cccccc;">DIV element 3. 
          </div>
          <div id="div4" style="background-color:#ffff00;">DIV element 4. 
          </div>
          <div id="div5" style="background-color:#0000ff;">DIV element 5. 
          </div>
      <script>
      function hs1()
      {
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div5").style.display = "none";
      }
      function hs2()
      {
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div5").style.display = "none";
      }
      function hs3()
      {
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div5").style.display = "none";
      }
      function hs4()
      {
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("div5").style.display = "none";
      }
      function hs5()
      {
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("div5").style.display = "block";
      }
      </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Yikes, that's some crappy html. <center>? Really?

Comment: So help me to do it better :-) but it does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both @Naota & @JoeFarrell
Your answers helped a lot. I adapted from what you posted and opted for the following - simply because at my stage of understanding I can follow it myself, not because it's better.
I put the displaying of the visible div in separate brackets so it didn't run 5 times. If there's something glaringly wrong please let me know.

```
 <script>
 function hs(divno){
     for(var i = 1 ; i <=5 ; i++){
         document.getElementById("div"+i).style.display = "none";
     }
     {
         document.getElementById("div"+divno).style.display = "block";
     }
         return false;
 }
 </script>
```

Links;

```
    <a href="#!" onclick="return hs(1)"> Content div1 </a> | 
    <a href="#!" onclick="return hs(2)"> Content div2 </a> | 
    <a href="#!" onclick="return hs(3)"> Content div3 </a> | 
    <a href="#!" onclick="return hs(4)"> Content div4 </a> | 
    <a href="#!" onclick="return hs(5)"> Content div5 </a>
```

Steve

Answer (score 1):

How about this 
DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/frnDq/4/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return hs(1)"> Content div1 </a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="return hs(2)"> Content div2 </a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="return hs(3)"> Content div3 </a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="return hs(4)"> Content div4 </a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="return hs(5)"> Content div5 </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function hs(divno){
    for(var i = 1 ; i <=5 ; i++){
        var display = (i == divno) ? "block":"none";
        document.getElementById("div"+i).style.display = display;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the function this way:

```
function hs(openPanel)
{
    for (var x = 1; x <= 5; ++x)
    {
        document.getElementById("div" + x).style.display = ((x == openPanel) ? "block" : "none");
    }
}
```

This ought to do exactly the same thing as the code you've already written, just without all the repetition. It now takes an argument indicating the panel that you want to be displayed, so instead of calling `hs2()`, you would call `hs(2)`.